# How does redirect and reverse work with kwargs in Django 2?

Tags: django, django-views

PaymentView function works correctly and redirects correctly to updateTransactions function if I do not include the locations variable.

Can you explain why adding locations variable as a kwarg breaks my function, and how to fix.

I get the error Something went wrong pt 2

## views.py

```
def PaymentView(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            user_id = get_user_id(request)
            locations = 4
        except:
            messages.info(request, "Something went wrong pt 1")
        try:
            return redirect(reverse('memberships:update-transactions',
                                kwargs={
                                    'sub_id': user_id,
                                    'locations': locations,
                                }))

        except:
            messages.info(request, "Something went wrong pt 2")

    return render(request, "stuff/stuff.html")

def updateTransactions(request, sub_id, locations):

    user_membership = get_user_membership(request)

    user_membership.locations = locations
    user_membership.sub_id = sub_id
    user_membership.save()

    return redirect(reverse('courses:list'))
```

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import PaymentView, updateTransactions

app_name = 'memberships'

urlpatterns = [
    path('payment/', PaymentView, name="payment"),
    path('update-transactions/<sub_id>', updateTransactions, name="update-transactions"),
]
```

Comment: There is no `locations` pattern in your `urls.py`. How do you pass that info to your `updateTransactions` view?

Comment: understood, could you show me how to pass locations into the updateTransactions view, without adding it to url like I did with sub_id

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't want to add it to your url pattern but you can use a querystring, e.g. `update-transactions/123?location=456`. You still won't be able to reverse that URL including the location id and you will have to append `?location=...` part to the reversed URL manually though.

Comment: thanks is there no way to pass locations to the updateTransaction function without including it in url patttern.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Just demonstrated an alternative way in my previous comment.